# Apache CXF Rest Services using Spring

Tags: spring, rest, cxf

I am using Apache CXF framework for implementing Rest WebService.I am using Spring 4.3.10 version.**Problem I am facing is I am not able to use** `<jaxrs:server>` **element**.I think there is some change in Spring upgraded version: previously it was configured something like below code snippet:

```
<jaxrs:server id="userManagerREST" address="/rest/UserManager">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="userManagerService"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref bean='jsonProvider' />
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

When I am using `<jaxrs>` tag I am getting below exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 29 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 29; columnNumber: 67; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'jaxrs:server'.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:614)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:515)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Please find below my namespace declaration in Spring configuration file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs-common.xsd">
```

So,as it can be seen from above code snippet I have included jaxrs namespace inspite of that it gave the above error.
But now I found a new tag : `<jaxrs:model>`.**[I got this option in eclipse
inside spring bean configuration file by using Cntrl+Space option]**.

I want to know its usage.
Anyone can provide any suitable example for this?

Comment: Code snippet looks ok and should work with the Spring version. What error message do you get and where have you noticed jaxrs:model?

Comment: @Dennis have replied to your comment in main post.Moreover I think there is some syntactical changes in Spring 4.3.10 which don't have that jaxrs tag anymore.

Comment: Well the jaxrs namespace is not part of Spring but CXF. So changing the Spring version shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had faced same problem few years back(now I no longer use xml based configuration), I don't remember its eclipse auto selection problem or the file was moved. Anyways  problem is your schema location, change it from `jaxrs-common.xsd` to `jaxrs.xsd`.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
 http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">
```

You can check the both the xsd's in `cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs.jar` `schemas` directory.